# looping foreach for certain steps(every request user sends)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to write a foreach that loops on a wanted certain step so for example if a user send me 2 rooms it just loops twice if the user sends 5 room it loops 5 times and here is what I tried:

```
$room_count = [1,2,3] //room ids for example
foreach($room_count as $room_counts){
 echo 'echo on eachstep'
}
```

I want to get the requests from `$request->all()` so I am not sure about saving that in array is a right thing to use for example here or not so I just need to do it in an array for now.

Comment: room will be just an integer or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($room_count); $i++) {
    //your loop body here
}
```

if you want to loop for certain amount of rooms.

You can't

> get the requests from $request->all()

, `$request->all()` contains only Request parameters like user's input.